# Bug in kendo ui grid lrt css in chrome

Tags: css, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, right-to-left

There is a bug in kendo ui grid rtl css in chrome.
If you notice example in Telerik site, you can see this bug:
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/rtl.html

When you go to page 6, the header and body, isn't align.

[image]
This error is in chrome (for me: V35) and in the firefox (V28) and IE(V11) does not this error.

You can same error in horizontal scrolling.
For example in ltr direction:

http://jsbin.com/otolop/2/edit

this is OK in all browser.
But in rtl direction:

http://jsbin.com/otolop/6/edit

It has error in chrome and has no error in firefox and IE.

How can I fix this error. Thanks alot.

Comment: Report it to Telerik. That is what I do when I find a bug in their controls. Same with any other 3rd party vendor. That is what they expect you to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
.k-grid-content {
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.k-grid-header-wrap {
    width: 102%;
}

.k-grid-footer-wrap {
    width: 102%;
}
```

Comment: This messes the grid when it is scrolled. (in FF)

Answer (score 1):

Apply table-layout `fixed` property to table of `role="grid"`. This worked for me.

```
.theme-01 .table-view table {
     table-layout: fixed;
}
```