# Kendo Grid header and data row columns are not aligned

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid

I have kendo grid.And problem is grid's header and data rows columns are not aligned properly.

[image]

Below is the kendo grid code :

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Product)
.Name("Grid")
.Scrollable(a => a.Height("auto"))    
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(o => o.ProductId).Sortable(true)
    .ClientTemplate("<a href='/Product/ProductEntry/#=ProductID#' target='_blank'>#=Product#</a>")
    .Title("Order #");
    columns.Bound(p => p.Name);
    columns.Bound(p => p.LastName);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Insurance);
    columns.Bound(p => p.LastUpdate);
})
.Pageable()
.Sortable()

    .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(false))
    .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(false))     
)
```

Comment: have you anywhere modified the width of the column?

Comment: What kendo's version do you have?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in kendo ui grid in chrome browser.
Do you test your problem in firefox?

You can read more about it in this question:

> [Bug in kendo ui grid lrt css in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823963/bug-in-kendo-ui-grid-lrt-css-in-chrome)

Comment: I'm getting this issue on FF only (Edge and Chrome wrorking fine)